# Trying to run CUDA sample from fresh install simply prints " make: Nothing to be done for `all' "

Tags: ubuntu, cuda, makefile, ubuntu-14.04, nvidia

I am absolutely lost trying to build CUDA 7.5 samples on Ubuntu 14.04! Please bear in mind I am very unfamiliar with makefiles and the like.

**Problem:**

I change directory and run the 'deviceQuery' sample:

> cd NVIDIA_CUDA-7.5_Samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery
>
> make

But the shell simply prints

> make: Nothing to be done for `all'.

**What I have tried:**

I have tried freshly installing Ubuntu, adding CUDA to my path by editing .bashrc, and running the commands again. The same message is printed for every sample.

I have installed MPI:

> sudo apt-get install libcr-dev mpich2 mpich2-doc

I've trawled through SO and all the issues with this message are related to the asker's code. I doubt my issue is the code, as it is stock from NVIDIA. I did try converting spaces to tabs in the makefiles, which changed nothing.

Because of the brevity of the message I can't seem to find any helpful comments on the internet; any answers would be greatly appreciated as I am genuinely stuck.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the time/date on your computer set correctly?  You may want to try `make clean` followed by `make`.  Also note that the [installation guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#compiling-examples) suggests running `make` from the samples directory, although I think your method should work.

Comment: The date is indeed correct; running the two commands you said in the deviceQuery directory gives me :

rm -f deviceQuery deviceQuery.o
rm -rf ../../bin/x86_64/linux/release/deviceQuery

followed by:
 
"/usr/local/cuda-7.5"/bin/nvcc -ccbin g++ -I../../common/inc  -m64    -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode   ....

Running make after that gives the same message

Comment: It looks like `make clean` first should get you going.  For whatever reason it seems that the samples were already built, so `make` is correct in reporting that "there is nothing to do."  I would suggest going up two levels to the main samples directory, and issue `make clean` from there, followed by `make -k`.  That will likely take some time.  After that is done, all the samples that can be built, should be built.  You can then run those samples as indicated in the installation guide I previously linked.  **But issuing `make` after the samples are already built, will not re-make anything**.

Comment: If you are in the deviceQuery directory, and you issue `make` and it reports "nothing to be done", then the most likely reason is that the `deviceQuery` sample is already built.  `make` in this case will not rebuild a sample that has already been built (unless you make changes to the source code, for example).  To demonstrate that, you should just try to run the sample in question.  For example, in the deviceQuery directory, try issuing the command `./deviceQuery`.  If the deviceQuery sample runs, then it means it was, in fact, already built.

Comment: Thank you for being so prompt! I realise now I misunderstood the meaning of 'make'. make creates the binary, but it must still be run. The binaries indeed run when I am root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CUDA Sample codes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#abstract) can be built by issuing a `make` command, either in one of the sample directories or at the main directory.

`make` in this case simply compiles the indicated code(s).  It does not run any of the compiled codes.  Furthermore, in typical usage, `make` will not rebuild codes that are already built, unless you subsequently edit a file  that the `Makefile` tracks.  If `make` determines that all the codes are built, up-to-date, and don't need recompiling, it will issue the typical "nothing to be done..." message.

To run a code, after building it with `make`, you can run the code directly as indicated in the [installation guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#compiling-examples), e.g.:

```
./deviceQuery
```

(if you are in the `deviceQuery` directory, or else in the samples `.../bin` directory)

I often suggest using `make -k` instead of `make` if you are building all the sample codes from the main directory.  This will cause `make` to continue even if one of the codes cannot be built, for example due to a missing dependency.